# How To Display Greet Message in SfB Bot on "ConversationUpdate" or "ContactRelationUpdate"

Tags: c#, botframework, skype-for-business

I have tried using both `ConversationUpdate` and `ContactRelationUpdate` for the bot created in MS Bot framework C# for S4B channel and published in hybrid environment.
I want the bot to initiate the conversation without user sending a message first, although I have implemented same in Skype channel but S4B doesn't reproduce same behavior.
It's a critical requirement for my team, the below code snippet should display welcome message on adding bot to contacts but doesn't seem to work:

```
else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate) {
    IContactRelationUpdateActivity contactupdate = activity;
    var reply = activity.CreateReply();
    using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity)) {
        var client = scope.Resolve();
        if (contactupdate.Action.Equals("add")) {
            reply.Text = "Welcome";
            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the reply message from a new connector instantiated with your message service URL

```
switch (message.Type) {
    //...
    case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
        reply = message.CreateReply("proactiveMessage");
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        break;
    //...
}
```

Comment: No luck with this also, the message is only displayed after user sends the first message but i want the bot to initiate the conversation.

Comment: Something is weird. Can you check if Skype for business sends two conversationUpdates to your bot (one being the user and the other one the bot) when initiating the connection to your bot? Also, keep in mind that the above code must check if the conversationUpdate is about the user, otherwise the proactive message will be displayed two times.

Comment: yes, it does. I have implemented logging and tracing in DB. The conversation update is for both user and bot just like in other channels. I have implemented same in Skype channel but don't know what's the issue in S4B

Comment: You should check if skype allows proactive message.

Comment: Check creating outbound bots in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview

Comment: I checked this link, but i think it's for initiating a new group chat with 2 users and bot. A new group chat would initiate and message will be displayed in that chat. I tried but "ConversationParameters" method expects a list of participants. Is it also possible to send outbound message to single user via bot without group chat ?

Comment: I don't see a restriction on outbound skype bots regarding just groups. As I see on that link, your bot must be S4B tenant-specific and you have to add https://api.skypeforbusiness.com/platformservice/botframework on the trusted Services URLs. Also: In addition, in order to initiate an outbound message, your bot must also have the Skype for Business identity of the user or users that bot will be messaging directly eg. user@contoso.com."

Comment: Thanks for all details . I have already ensured the above listed points but main issue was the code snippet targets initiating a new group chat (useful in cases where user wants to connect to human agent with bot in background). I tried with same snippet after changing list of participants to single user but the method expects list of users i.e IList<ChannelAccount> only.

Comment: I tried "CreateDirectConversation" method instead at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector but still no response from S4B bot.

Comment: It's given in microsoft bot framework documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector that "CreateConversation" is for groupchat only which is what is given at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview for outbound bots